# use "must" to conclude something

Tags: modal-verbs

A: I wonder how you get past security. B: I suppose you must have (to show)/showed some form of ID. Does the phrase "to show" and "showed" have the same meaning in this sentence?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*You must have showed* means “it appears very likely that you showed.”

*You must have to show* means “it appears very likely that one is required to show.”